# Como usar a classe do csrf no codeigniter com evento onchange?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, csrf

Estou com a seguinte situação:

**Formulário**

```
<?php
    $atributos = array('id'=>'cadloja','class'=>'form-inline','role'=>'form','data-toggle'=>'validator');
    echo form_open('',$atributos);
?>
    <select class="form-control" id="grupo">
        <option value="<?= 'retorno_ajax' ?>"><?= 'retorno_ajax' ?></option>
    </select>

<?php
    echo form_close();
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#grupo').change(function () {
    $('#div_retorno').load('lista_grupos');
}
```

Reparem que não estou usando requisições ajax nem submetendo o formulário no evento `onchange`. Com o `csrf` ativo, o `onchange` não funciona mais.

Até encontrei algumas respostas no `SOen`, mas em todas, seria forçado a fazer uma outra requisição ajax no evento `onchange`. Li na documentação do `CI` também que é possível excluir uma pagina da verificação `csrf`:

```
 $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('controllerx/metodox');
```

Essa opção é a que dá menos trabalho, mas ficaria seguro ainda?

Então, é isso... tem alguma maneira de fazer diferente dessas duas que falei?
Obrigado.

Comment: Claro que vc está usando requisições. _load()_ é uma requisição. E como o _csrf_ está interferindo, ela está sendo feita via _$_POST_. Mostre o código todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desculpe a demora, é verdade, após várias pesquisas, encontrei a resposta. Para "padronizar" o trabalho em qualquer caso, vi que utilizando ajax é mais fácil, e também, da pra usar o `when` e `then` do `jquery` em conjunto.

A questão é que o `CI` só atualiza automaticamente o token se a página inteira for recarregada, como este não é o caso, obrigatoriamente tem que se retornar o novo token do `controller` para a view.

Se tentar simplesmente utilizar o `echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();` diretamente na view, não funciona. Tem de vir do `controller` ou até mesmo do `model`.